# Plotting image Red channel by intensity

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Okay, So i'm trying to take the red channel of an image, and plot it (preferably 3d) to an image.  The image is 480x640 (or thereabouts), and is taken from a webcam.  I'm currently using scipy, numpy, and python to get the image, extract he red channel, and process it.  That all works.

However, when i try to plot it, 2 different problems occur, depending on how I try to plot:

1)  Width mismatch, it doesn't like that the image isn't square.

2)  It only plots one row of the image (x val = 0, all y vals).

I've attached the relevent code.  Comments are everywhere, for when i try different ways.

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    #ax = Axes3D(fig)
    #ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    X = [range(480), range(480)]
    Y = [range(480), range(480)]
    #X = range(len(self.R))
    #Y = range(len(self.R))
    '''
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.resize(self.R, (480, 480)) , rstride=1, cstride=10, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    ax.set_zlim3d(0.0, 255.0)

    ax.w_zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(100))
    ax.w_zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.03f'))

    m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
    m.set_array(self.frame_in)
    fig.colorbar(m)
    np.savetxt("tmp.txt", self.R)
    '''
    #np.savetxt("tmp.out", self.R[0])
    #np.savetxt("tmp.out1", self.R[1])
    #np.savetxt("tmp.txt", self.frame_in, "[ %s ]", "\t")
    #plt.subplot(212)
    #x, y = self.R.shape
    #x = range(x)
    #y = range(y)

    #X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    plt.scatter(X, Y, self.R)
    #plt.pcolormesh(self.R)
    #plt.colorbar()

    #ax.scatter(x, y, self.R, c='r', marker='o')

    plt.show()
```

I can clean up the code if needed, but i wanted everyone to see the multiple ways i've tried.  Am i missing something really stupid simple?  It doesn't make sense that it will work with the first row, and not all of them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post a runnable piece of code, maybe using a generated image?  Please add minimal extra code, but something runnable would help.

Comment: Do you have the matrix of the image? In any case, images with [nx,ny,4] shape can be passes to matplotlib.pyplot.imshow. [nx,ny,0] is the R channel, [nx,ny,1] is the G channel and [nx,ny,2] is the B channel. [nx,ny,3] is the "alpha" channel for transparency. If you pass an image with [nx,ny] shape, it is plotted assuming some of the available colormaps...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`pyplot.imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

```
plt.cmap('Reds')
plt.imshow(self.R)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That wouldn't work for me for some reason.  Do you have any knowledge about why the hxw mismatch is so messy? Or why it would only be plotting one row?